# RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile not working with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to run

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
```

I am getting an error NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec. How do I get rid of this error?

Some context: I'm trying to get my images and css files precompiled before sending them to AWS Beanstalk. Much like this question RoR App: "The asset 'application.css' is not present in the asset pipeline" after moving to production server [RoR App: "The asset 'application.css' is not present in the asset pipeline" after moving to production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56753564/ror-app-the-asset-application-css-is-not-present-in-the-asset-pipeline-afte)

Stack Trace:

```
[15:49:45] [master]     /xxx/CaIng : RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile --trace
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `load_missing_constant'
/xxx/CaIng/lib/tasks/custom_rspec.rake:3:in `<main>'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `each'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:515:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:459:in `load_tasks'
/xxx/CaIng/Rakefile:6:in `<main>'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:22:in `block in perform'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'

Caused by: 
NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:59:in `load_missing_constant'
/xxx/CaIng/lib/tasks/custom_rspec.rake:3:in `<main>'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `each'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:515:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:459:in `load_tasks'
/xxx/CaIng/Rakefile:6:in `<main>'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:22:in `block in perform'
/Users/flo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/xxx/CaIng/.gems/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'aws-sdk'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise'
```

Comment: Could you post full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have those gems on development group, only byebug should be on both groups.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I moved gems to match what you have above. Then I saved. I ran bundle install. Then I ran RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile again and I got the same error.