# CircleCI + Rails 7 + Yarn + assets:precompile - `yarn: not found`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, asset-pipeline, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am using Circle CI to run RSpec tests on a Rails project. I'm new to CircleCI, so I'm piecing together a build script from examples.

My tests are failing because `application.css` is not in the asset pipeline. Here is the exact error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
  The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

I figured this is because the assets are not being precompiled. So I added `bundle exec rails assets:precompile` to my `config.yml`. I also included `cimg/node:19.2.0` to provide `yarn`.

However, when the build runs, CircleCI reports that the `yarn` command cannot be found. Here is the exact error:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
sh: 1: yarn: not found
rake aborted!
jsbundling-rails: Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed and `yarn build` runs without errors
/home/circleci/my_project/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/jsbundling-rails-1.0.3/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/circleci/my_project/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => javascript:build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

My understanding is that `yarn` should be provided by the `cimg/node:19.2.0`, so I'm not sure why it cannot be found.

I've posted my `config.yml` as a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/johnnyicon/d805a1c178563d37c837b4eb2e5bb776

- `Line 22` is where I added `cimg/node:19.2.0`
- `Lines 53-55` is where I added `bundle exec assets:precompile`

It might be important to note that my tests were running fine (and passing) until I started testing view-related code.

Comment: try to use cimg/ruby:3.1.0-node

Comment: Thanks @SoufyaneBouchaala! That fixed the `yarn: not found` issue. I can see the assets being precompiled, but `circleci` still cannot find `application.css`?

Comment: try to check configs in production.rb, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614166/rails-application-css-not-in-asset-pipeline